# Error when using `link` as a class name in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Consider a simple program in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

class link {};

int main() {
    link alink;
}
```

Compiling it with g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 gives the following error:

> test.cpp:6:8: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘alink’

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because link is also a posix function and the function name hides the class name.

You can say `class link alink;` but better put your class into a new namespace or rename it.

Comment: That's not very feasible. If you compile using the `-std=c++98` switch, the compiler shouldn't consider any non-standard functions.